# Laptop showing connected but no internet access?

Tags: windows-7, windows

Windows 7 on my lap top.  I have a Sprint 3G/4G wireless.  I'll connect to the internet and it shows a strong connection.  But I will not be able to access the internet.  Not just to my wifi, but any wifi.  Like last night I was at a Flying J trucks stop and attempted to connect to their internet.  Tells me the same thing.  Load a page and it says "HTTP No Response".

I'm not a computer whiz so this is all outta my league.  When this happens, what do I do to repair it?  Also, it will show DENNISRYAN2 as the internet source instead of just DENNISRYAN.  I don't understand what the "2" is.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Where do you normally connect to the Internet? Has it always been like that? Do you have any WiFi at home, for example. which you had set up before?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if you're trying to do two things at once. The Sprint cellular internet card and your WiFi shouldn't be used at the same time. Try removing the Sprint card, then connecting to WiFi.

Comment: Sometimes you have to quit or disable the 3g/4g software as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the "network sharing center" by right-clicking the wireless connection's tray icon.  If there is a red x in there or yellow exclamation, click on it and Windows will attempt to troubleshoot the problem.

If that fails, you can clear out your wireless settings by uninstalling and reinstalling the drivers in Device Manager.  Just right-click on the driver and choose uninstall.  And then from the Action menu choose "Scan for Hardware Changes".  You will need to re-setup your wireless network, because this will erase all settings and passwords.

If that fails, try resetting Winsock by doing the following:

1. Click on Start button.
2. Type Cmd in the Start Search text box.
3. Press Ctrl-Shift-Enter keyboard shortcut to run Command Prompt as Administrator. Allow elevation request.
4. Type "netsh winsock reset" without the quotes in the Command Prompt shell, and then press the Enter key.
5. Restart the computer.

   You may also need to reset TCP/IP Internet Protocol stack.
6. Click on Start button.
7. Type Cmd in the Start Search text box.
8. Press Ctrl-Shift-Enter keyboard shortcut to run Command Prompt as Administrator. Allow elevation request.
9. Type "netsh int ip reset" without the quotes in the Command Prompt shell, and then press the Enter key.
10. Restart the computer.

If all that does not fix it it may be a defective wireless card